# SQL to deduct total sales from total purchase based on date

Tags: sql

I am trying to calculate total purchase units left after sales unit in time based. Below is my sample table and required output underneath.

```
fno   pno   vdate              pdate    units   ttype
1234    1   1-Jan-2011     1-Jan-2011   100    p
12      1   1-Jan-2012     1-Jan-2011   100    p
1234    1   1-Jan-2012     1-Jan-2011   100    p
1234    1   1-Jan-2012     1-Jan-2011   100    p
12      1   1-Jan-2013     1-Jan-2011   100    s
1234    1   1-Jan-2013     1-Jan-2011   150    s
```

Output should be

```
fno  pno    vdate        pdate    units ttype
1234    1   1-Jan-2012  1-Jan-2011  50  p
1234    1   1-Jan-2012  1-Jan-2011  100 p
```

Here `ttype` is transaction type 's' means sales and 'p' means purchase. I would like to have SQL query which can calculate units based on order on which purchase was made.

Like if look at 1234 fno in 1-jan-2011 100 units were purchased and second purchase was on 1-jan-2012 of 100 units each. Same kind of transaction happend with fno = 12 and units are 100 (purchase) and 100 units have been sold on 1-jan-2013.

Here is SQL

```
select (t3.pUnits - t2.sUnits) as sb, t1.fno, t1.ttype, t1.vdate from 
dbtrans as t1
left join (
    select sum(units) as sUnits, fno, pno
    from dbtrans
    group by fno, pno, ttype having ttype = 's'
) as t2 on t1.fno = t2.fno

left join (
    select sum(units) as pUnits, fno, pno
    from dbtrans
    group by fno, pno, ttype having ttype = 'p'
) as t3 on t1.fno = t3.fno
group by t1.vdate
```

So calculation should be made on vdate basis for transaction type.

If still I am missing anything please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apart from an answer to your question, the `having ttype='s'` should be in the where clause instead, same for `having ttype='p'`.

Comment: Relating to my previous comment, you would not group on ttype then, just fno and pno.

Comment: @TT., I tried it too but no luck.

Comment: It's just one error in your query aside from any other problems.

Comment: I have very little time to write the query for you. As a general rule, if you have problems with a complex query try to write out the 'algorithm' you need to get the result in steps (in english, not SQL). Try to write a query for each step to make it simpler to get to your final 'complex' query.